# Detecting maximum pixel distance in a image

Tags: python, image, pycharm, distance, detection

I'm a beginner at python and pycharm. I have a question while working on the project

Can you tell me how to make the code for detecting maximum distance in a image just as below? I saw some code using MATLAB in the previous post, but I wonder how to make it with python code.

My goal is to draw a line (just like a red line in post below.) and mark its distance in the image.

post : http://georgepavlides.info/how-to-detect-the-maximum-pixel-distance-in-a-binary-image/

Comment: By "maximum pixel distance", you mean you want to find the two white pixels in the image that are farthest apart? And do you just want the distance, or the coordinates of those pixels? Please include the relevant information in your question - linking to a source is fine, as long as the relevant bits are here for future reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added the information as you said. Please reply if there should be needed additional information.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at writing the required Python code yourself? What libraries are you using? Please share your efforts and where you're running into problems.

Comment: I just uploaded the code. I extracted the best.pt file using the YOLOv5 model for image training. Based on this, i'm at the stage of predicting the label of the test image in 'data/images' using PyCharm. Next I want to show the maximum distance of the image, but I wonder what part of the code should be modified.

I added another image which is extracted from my model.

Comment: @xXcCvV Your updated code in python is huge and there are a lot of details in it. I think it is better to edit it for post and just parts that are important in question should be written. In this way you can get your answer faster. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this code and hope it solve your problem:

```
from PIL import Image
import math

im = Image.open('C:\\pic\\1.jpg') # Can be many different formats.
pix = im.load()
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')

ls_white=[]

for i in range(rgb_im.size[0]):
    for j in range(rgb_im.size[1]):
        if(rgb_im.getpixel((i, j))!=(0,0,0)):
            ls_white.append((i,j))      

max_distance=-1

for i in range(len(ls_white)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(ls_white)):
        distance=math.dist(ls_white(i),ls_white(j))>max_distance
        if(distance>max_distance):
            max_distance=distance
```

I test it for 50px*30px (1500 pixels) image and it worked.

Remmber: for large images it may get your memory full, so you have to make some optimization and remove some impure pixels.

First I get any pixel that has color not equal to Black, and save it's position into ls_white.

Second I check distance from first point in ls_white to others, and do it for other pixels, and if distance is bigger, will save it to max_distance.

I propose that try it from a tiny simple picture with few number of white points.

[image: sample image I made for test of my code]

Comment: Really appreciate for your answer :)  I'll apply the code you gave me.

Comment: Your welcome. would you make answer as accepted and vote up? Thanks.